# execute a command using java and save generated output in another directory

Tags: java, process, command

I am working on an eclipse rcp product where I need to run a command from one directory and need to save the output in another directory.

The output of a command is a file.

I am not getting how to do that.

My code is like this which is not working.

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process  p = r.exec(("CMD /C cd D:\\dir1\\bin" + " && " + command),
            null, new File("D:\\Data\\test"));
```

so, command needs to run from dir1/bin and the output of this command is a file which should save in data/test.

But from the above code, the output(ie. generated file) is saved in dir1/bin which is not expected.

Comment: Runtime.exec is obsolete.  Its replacement, for many years, has been the [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class.  You should not specify your command as a single String, but rather as a series of command line arguments.  Without seeing your command, I cannot tell you how to properly do that.

Answer (score 0):

`echo This is a command > output.txt`

Try and add the '**> output.txt**' to the end of the command to insert it into a file

Answer (score 0):

You can use the InputStream given by the process object (p.getInputStream()) and a FileOutputStream to a file.
Create a new Thread with an endless while-loop, read the characters within that and write them to the file.

```
Process p = ....
InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("output.txt"));
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            char c = (char)is.read();
            if (c > -1) {
                fos.write(c);
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```

I did not test the code but it should work.